# Is it possible that a non repeating expansion in a variable base to be rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

or the reverse, where a repeating expansion in a variable base to be rational?
been trying some trial and error cases without success

by variable base we mean each digit can be in a different base but any digit can occur as many times in the same base or not

Just in case anybody tries to pull a fast one no base $\sqrt 2$, $\pi$ , $e$ etc. can not have the irrational number itself as base, that would make this trivial.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by a variable base?

Comment: @quasi bade i or first digit in base 3 , second in base 5 , or first digit in base 1/2 , second in base 5, 3rd in I  how is that for variable bars. Can also use Maurice as base as well but I don't think any combination of that will ever end up being a scaler number

Comment: Can you use bases 3,9,27,81,... ?

Comment: @quasi : sure, but that is just base 3 and the answer is obvious

Comment: But the digits can vary, non-repeating

Comment: @quasi : yes, and that means it is not ratational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $.1141144114441144441144444\dots$, where the 1s are in base 3, and the 4s are in base 9. The expansion is nonrepeating, but it represents $${1\over3}+{1\over9}+{4\over9^2}+{1\over3\cdot9^2}+{1\over9^3}+{4\over9^4}+{4\over9^5}+\cdots$$ which is $${4\over9}+{4\over9^2}+{4\over9^3}+{4\over9^4}+{4\over9^5}+\cdots={1\over2}$$ which is rational.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment than an answet.

If the expansion is of the form
$x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} d_k/B_k$
where $B_{k+1} >B_k$
and $0\le d_k < B_{k+1}/B_k$
(the standard decimal system
has $B_k=10^k$)
then the representation is unique
if and only if
$B_{k+1}/B_k$
is an integer for all $k$.

In the factorial system,
with $B_k=k!$,
the representation terminates
if and only if
the number is rational.
In this system,
$e$ has
$d_k=1$
for all $k$,
so this transcendental number
has a repeating
representation.

Answer (score 1):

Using bases $\,3,3^2,3^3,3^4,\ldots\,$ with corresponding digits $\,1,2,3,4,\ldots\;$ yields

$${\large{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}}} = \frac{3}{4}$$